# Changing the formula of cell in all the sheets of the archive

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel archive that contains about 100 sheets i want write VBA macro so that cell A1 of each sheet will contain this formula:

```
=RECHERCHEV(B2;'SUMUP'!B$1:H478;3;FAUX)
```

This is my macro

```
Sub WorksheetLoop()

     ' Declare Current as a worksheet object variable.
     Dim Current As Worksheet

     ' Loop through all of the worksheets in the active workbook.
     For Each Current In Worksheets

     'Change the formula of cell A1 
        Current.Range("A1").Formula ="=RECHERCHEV(B2;'SUMUP'!B$1:H478;3;FAUX)"
     Next
End Sub
```

When i execute this macro i got error of execution '1004', Note that SUMUP is a sheet of my archive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VBA is very EN-US-centric. The [Range.Formula property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838835.aspx) expects input as EN-US; you can use the [Range.FormulaLocal property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838851.aspx) if you want to use the non-EN-US Office language pack FR-FR regionals.

Use one of these:

```
Current.Range("A1").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(B2,'SUMUP'!B$1:H478, 3, False)"
Current.Range("A1").FormulaLocal = "=RECHERCHEV(B2;'SUMUP'!B$1:H478;3;FAUX)"

Current.Range("A1").FormulaLocal = "=REMPLACER(CELLULE(""filename"";A1);1;TROUVE(""]"";CELLULE(""filename"";A1));"""")"
```

Comment: the formula that you gave me works fine however this formula :Current.Range("A1").FormulaLocal = "=REMPLACER(CELLULE("filename";A1);1;TROUVE("]";CELLULE("filename";A1));"")" won't work. i have compilation error, could you please help me to solve this problem

Comment: Remember that you have to double up quotes within a quoted string.