# Formula Sheetname combo dosen't work

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

So i want to ad a formula to cells with vba but i have the sheetname in the formula, how do i get around this problem?

```
Sub MatchaFormel(A As String, B As String)
Dim j As Integer
j = 1
 Worksheets("Sammanställning").Range(B & 3).Activate
 Do
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate

    ActiveCell.Formula = "=ANTAL.OMF('Component List'!$" & A & "$2:$" & A & "S$3001;E3)"
    j = j + 1
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, -1).Activate
 Loop Until ActiveCell.Value = ""

End Sub
```

So my problem is the 'Component List' part of the code. The ANTAL.OMF is COUNTIFS in english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you **don't** want a worksheet name specified then simply remove it:

```
'Component List'!
```

Any time you have a string that you're trying to troubleshoot, just display the string itself so you can easier see the problem.

**For example:**  (for troubleshooting)

If your VBA is:

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=ANTAL.OMF('Component List'!$" & A & "$2:$" & A & "S$3001;E3)"
```

then add a couple line before it, copy-and-pasting the string into a `Debug.Print` statement.  For example:

```
Debug.Print "=ANTAL.OMF('Component List'!$" & A & "$2:$" & A & "S$3001;E3)"
Stop
```

Run the code and when it breaks at the `Stop`, hit CTRL+G (for the Immediate Window) to see what formula it's giving you.  If necessary, copy & paste that formula to a worksheet and see if it works as-is.

If not, your problem should be clear.

---

It looks like you have some confusion with your single/double quotes.  In order to include a `"` double quotes in a formula, use a double set of them (`""`).

**Perhaps the line that you want is:**

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=ANTAL.OMF("$A" & "$2:$" & A & "S$3001;E3)"
```

Comment: .Formula will not add a non-EN-US formula. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32587622/changing-the-formula-of-cell-in-all-the-sheets-of-the-archive/32587940#32587940) for more info. Needs to be COUNTIFS with comma separators or .FormulaLocal to use regionals.

Comment: This fixed it.  Thanks

ActiveCell.FormulaLocal = "=ANTAL.OMF('Component List'!$" & A & "$2:$" & A & "S$3001;" & B & j + 2 & ")" '